# Adjust format of generated CSV-File

Tags: php, laravel, csv, export

I am generating a very small CSV-File with only 4 columns and it works fine. When I press the designated button it downloads and I can open it and all the wanted data is present.

However the layout is very weird and it doesn't look good. Here is how it looks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/klXcw.png

In the upper row are the column names and in the row below is the data.

Here is my code that generates the file:

```
public function exportData(Bewerbungen $bewerbung) {

        $query = Portal::query()->where('email', '=', $bewerbung->bewerber_email)->get();

        $headers = [
            "Content-type"        => "text/csv",
            "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=bewerberdaten.csv",
            "Pragma"              => "no-cache",
            "Cache-Control"       => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
            "Expires"             => "0",
        ];
        $columns  = ['id', 'email', 'vorname', 'nachname', 'telefon'];
        $callback = function () use ($query, $columns) {
            $file = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 
            fputcsv($file, $columns);
            foreach ($query as $res) {
                fputcsv($file, [$res->id, $res->email, $res->vorname, $res->nachname, $res->telefon]);
            }
            fclose($file);
        };
        return Response::stream($callback, 200, $headers);
    }
```

I tried to play around with content encoding, but it is my first time working with csv and file exporting so I have no clue if it is the right direction.

Edit: Better screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HvhA.png

Comment: What looks "weird" to you, and what do you expect instead ?

Comment: @JoffreySchmitz ah I just saw I took the screenshot bit too small. I want them to have each a own column and not being so tight together

Comment: What program are you using to view the csv? Everything seems to look normal.

Comment: @JacobMulquin Excel, Text edit, Xcode.. so a couple. it always looks so weird. I googled a bit and came across Laravel Excel library and working my way into this now :D

Comment: In Excel, did you try the explicit "From Text/CSV" command?

Comment: Which command do you mean? I only have content-type set to text/csv

Comment: In the Ribbon, go to the Data tab, then "From Text" on the left hand side. It brings up a screen where you can set the delimiter of the file, it will detect encoding, etc

Comment: @JacobMulquin I am not sure if I found what you meant but it is tidier now. The issue is my Professor will grade the project and I cant ensure that he has the same settings to view the data in a tidy way :/

Comment: Oh I got it with Laravel Excel library!! :D I just have to change "excel_compatability" to true in the config/excel.php file! :D

Comment: Great work on figuring it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to install this:
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html

And then changing the variable `'excel_compatibility'    => false` to `true`

It is inside the `config/excel.php` file